# Rxjs - Table with buttons, wait a certain time after last button pressed before request

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I would like your help with something I have in mind to be used for things like deleting notifications.

Basically, my users have a list of notifications which they can mark as read.
Now, my back-end is very sluggish (and I have no control over it).
Right now, when a user clicks on the notification's **✉** button :

1. A request to the back-end is made to mark the notification, then after a back-end response, refresh data with another request;
2. The entry is modified in app memory, *the view is modified*
3. Refreshed data from **1.** comes back, *the view is modified*

This tanslates to something like this (using Angular's `HttpClient`) :

```js
markAsRead(id: string): void {
  this.http.post(url, body, options)
  .subscribe(() => this.reloadNotifications());

  this.markAsReadInternal(id);
}
```

Here comes the trouble : when my user decides to do a single action, all is good. But when the user decides to read many notifications, the view can be altered many times as the data refresh.

I can see a way of preventing the problem, but that would mean

1. Button is clicked;
2. Store the id in an array;
3. Wait for X milliseconds for another click;
4. If a click occured back to **2.**, else
5. Send the request with the array of ids and refresh the data

Any help to translate that into rxjs code?

*Bonus point*: My data is refreshed every 5 seconds in any case...

Comment: You need `throttleTime`.

Comment: Sounds promising, actually. But just to be sure about what you mean, do I need to throttle the data refresh?

Comment: No, you need to throttle button clicks. Convert them into a stream and pipe(throttle) that stream.

Comment: Hum... could you perhaps give me an example? I must admit that I have never done that (plus the buttons are built with the angular html template)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, no room here.

Answer (score 1):

Button clicks call a function:

```
<button (click)="buttonClicked()"></button>
```

Store button clicks as a subject/observable:

```
private buttonClick$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Emit a new value for each click:

```
buttonClicked() {
  this.buttonClick$.next();
  // this.buttonClick$.emit(); // One of these is deprecated, can't remember which
}
```

Get button clicks throttled:

```
getButtonClicks() {
  return this.buttonClick$.pipe(
    throttleTime(5000)
  )
}
```

And then you can do something like:

```
getButtonClicks().subscribe(() => {
  // Do something with throttled button clicks
});
```

To make an observable from clicks you might also use this instead of your subject:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html

Edit:

So you want to save clicks inbetween throttling.
You can do it like this:

```
getButtonClicks() {
  return this.buttonClick$.pipe(
    buffer(this.buttonClick$.pipe(
      debounceTime(5000)
    ))
  )
}
```

And then you still call your BE API:

```
getButtonClicks().subscribe((clicks) => {
  // Do something with debounced clicks
  // console.log(clicks);
});
```

Comment: I like that, I find it elegant and will keep it in mind, but what I want to do is the opposite. My user can click as much as they want, but requests to my back-end must be sent at most one time every X seconds with the ids collected from the clicks... Thank you for taking the time to answer, though. :)

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, that sounds nice. I will try this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It kind of works, yeah. Still need to tinker with the concept, but thanks for giving me something to start with :)

Answer (score 0):

You may better use `buffer` & `debounceTime` then `throttleTime`.

## `throttleTime` vs `debounceTime`

`throttleTime` emits first(I think its not what you want) and then wait for N ms.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer - `buffer`

`debounceTime` waits for N ms after last event and emits if no further events emitted.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime - `debounceTime`

`buffer(observable)` means `collect items until parameter observable emits`, and `debounceTime(N)` means `N ms after last emit`.

You can understand it as "'collect items until'(`buffer`) '1000ms after last click'(`debounceTime`)".

This is working simulation.

```js
// Mock notification button click event
const click$ = Rx.fromEvent(document.getElementById('notification'), 'click');

// Mock http request
function markAsRead(...ids: string[]) {
  return Rx.timer(Math.random() * 2000)
    .pipe(
      RxOp.mapTo('marked!'),
    );
}

click$
  .pipe(
    RxOp.mapTo((Math.random() * 1000).toFixed()), // Mock ID, random
    RxOp.bufferWhen(() => click$.pipe(RxOp.debounceTime(1000))), // your 'certain time'
    RxOp.switchMap(ids => markAsRead(...ids)), // call http request
  )
  .subscribe(value => log(value));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/kuroneko0441-rxjs-test-1ynvps?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50